# How to join on multiple columns in .NET Entity Framework with extension methods?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, extension-methods

I am trying to perform a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM pd AS p
JOIN wh AS w
ON p.ID = w.ID
AND p.ln = w.ln
AND p.wID = w.WID
WHERE w.zID = '1234'
```

So far I can access the tables like this:

```
WEntity entity = new WEntity();
// I can call the entities like this: entity.pd and entity.wh.
```

I googled and found examples with one column, eg.

```
var data = entity.pd
                 .Join(entity.wh,
                       p => p.ID,
                       w => w.ID,
                       (p, w) => p).Where( ... );
```

Comment: Do you have the collection properties set up on your data classes? Please show them. You shouldn't need to do a Join if everything is properly related.

Comment: I don't have collection properties. The tables existed before the application did, so this was created database first instead of code first.

Answer (score -1):

This might help - it's got a couple of joins assuming that is what you are after:

`post = (From ca In db.be_Categories Join c In db.be_PostCategory On ca.CategoryID Equals (c.CategoryID) Join p In db.be_Posts On c.PostID Equals (p.PostId) Where p.PostRowID = id Select New PostDTO With {.PostCategory = Nothing, .PostDateCreated = p.DateCreated, .PostGuid = p.PostId, .PostId = p.PostRowID, .PostText = p.PostContent, .PostTitle = p.Title}).FirstOrDefault`